# img error not detected in FF

Tags: jquery

I am using the following method to replace missing images with a placeholder img. Works fine, except in Firefox. Any ideas why FF doesn't detect the error?

```
$(function(){
    $('#id img').error(function() {
        $(this).attr('src','placeholder.jpg');
    });
});
```

Also tried `.bind('error', handler)` with the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you working locally?

Docs say it might not work when using local...

http://api.jquery.com/error/

Answer (score 0):

http://objectmix.com/javascript/307896-img-error-works-safari-but-not-firefox-leopard-what-can-i-doto-fix.html

> In Firefox imgObject.onerror handler is intentionally killed in any
>   form, even for hardcoded in the source  elements (internal
>   security exception raised) - maybe to prevent any possibility of
>   content sniffing or I don't know. AFAICT nothing you can do about it.
>   Either screw on Firefox, or move your logic server-side which is
>   suggested: so get directory check results from server script over some
>   ajaxoid.

Comment: Please at least summarize the document you are linking to. If Stack Overflow is a reference, not a forum. If it outlives that link then we have a question with an answer containing nothing but a broken link.

Comment: interesting. are you aware of another method? It's really temporary so any workaround is welcome.